# how to get reference of server in deployd (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using deployd and have a need to access current server object in a background thread i.e. There is no request/response or session involved. Is there any way to get this reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/3795019

This gist shows how you can grab the server object. Keep in mind that the resource may be constructed multiple times while a server is running.

Comment: So, does it mean every resource gets injected with option object which has server?

Comment: Yes. An upcoming release will have `process.server` so you will not need a `Resource`to get to the server. If you need this now checkout https://github.com/deployd/deployd/tree/feature/process-server.